# How chore can be associated to many models associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am a noob trying to make my first app. to allow my kids to log their chores.  My question pertains to the tables I might envision:

chores (for the parents to post available chores and the value)
kids (I have 3 kids and they will each have a need for 'credit' for work done)
wallet (where the chores done by kids are stored)

my guess is that this works.

but the associations are confusing the heck out of me.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Chore
 has_many :kids :through => wallet

Kid
 ??

Wallet
 has_many :kids
 has_many :chores

 wallet contains kid_id and chore_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

First let model the fact that one chore can be associated to many kids

```
Kid:
  has_many :kid_chore
  has_many :chores, :through=>:kid_chore

KidChore: 
  belongs_to :kid
  belongs_to :chore

Chore:
  has_many :kid_chore
  has_many :kid, :through=>:kid_chore
```

You can use Wallet for the name of the KidChore table if you like.

Second each Chore is done or not done

```
class Chore < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :chore do |t|
      t.string   :name
      t.date     :start_date
      t.date     :end_date
      t.string   :status  # done or not done

      #...all the field that you like
      
      t.timestamps
    end
    
  end
```

def self.down
drop_table :chore
end
end

Now you want to now how much of the chore each kid has done

```
    class KidChore < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def self.up
        create_table :kid_chore do |t|
          t.integer :kid_id
          t.integer :chore_id
          t.integer   :percentage_done  # done or not done
          #...all the field that you like
          t.timestamps
        end
        
      end
    
      def self.down
        drop_table :kid_chore
      end
end
```

Hope this help.